# SmartLock for Password never appear after pressing "Never" option

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

We are trying to implement Smart Lock for Passwords for our Android app. Everything worked fine until i've pressed "Never" option after entering my credentials in login form. Now SmartLock form never appear on the screen even after deletion from "Never save" list.

I've deleted my app from "Never save" list; checked that app not listed here passwords.google.com; checked that i don't see my app in SmartLock settings. Nothing helped...it still doesn`t appear...

Can anyone help to figure out what problem is?

Answer (score 2):

1. Login your Chrome browser on your PC with the Google account you pressed "Never" option.
2. Input "chrome://settings/passwords" as URL.
3. You would find your app name under "Never Saved". Press the "X" next to it.

[image: Chrome password setting]]